# (NODE) Para que serve um processador com multiplos nucleos, se o NodeJS roda somente em uma thread?

Tags: node.js, paralelismo

Exemplo:

Se eu quero montar um servidor, então, tenho que me "preocupar" com o clock e não com a quantidades de nucleos ?

Tipo, se eu tenho dois processadores para comprar

Processador X -> 8 Nucleos de 2.0GHz &&
Processador Y -> 4 Nucleos de 3.0GHz

Seria mais vantajoso comprar o processador Y para meu servidor ? Pois ja que o NodeJS só roda em uma thread/Nucleo , então, comprar o processador X seria "desperdicio" de 7 nucleos e no processador Y um "desperdicio" de 3 nucleos, e ainda com a vantagem de ter um clock maior !

Não sei se estou errado, mas, eu entendi por isso.

Se essa minha "teoria" estiver certa, o que devo fazer ? Mudar de linguagem ou aplicar Threads no meu APP ?

Comment: Para outras tecnologias usarem? O fato do Node ser limitado é um problema só dele. Claro que dá para usar outras coisas junto na máquina, dá para usar processos diferentes, embora tem cenário simples e tem cenário complicado porque seria forçado para resolver uma deficiência do Node. Não quer dizer que haverá desperdício, depende de como usa. Eu não vou falar para mudar de linguagem, mas é o que eu faria :) São duas coisas diferentes. Claro que depende um pouco do caso, pode ser que não precise disso tudo. Não existe resposta absoluta para essas coisas. Por isso não é simples responder isso.

Comment: E no caso de o seguinte: Digamos que eu quero criar um servidor de um jogo tal q eu comprei (exemplo: CS 1.6), ai eu vou no site e tal e baixo o servidor pra eu mesmo proprio hospedar... digamos que eu vá hospedar 3 servidores (3 portas diferentes) tudo no mesmo PC (pelo motivo de cada servidor rodar um mapa diferente). Entao, ao rodar esses 3 servidores ao mesmo tempo, será q o PC faz o parelismo automatico com outras Threads ? ou vai rodar tudo na mesma thread ?

Comment: Não, computadores só fazem o que softwares mandam fazer.

Comment: Tlgd, eu pensei que o Sistema Operacional tivesse alguma funcao "inteligente" de jogar um processo para outra Thread no caso de q a Thread principal estivesse "lotada"

Comment: Não é o seu programa que vai gerenciar diretamente o uso dos nucleos, geralmente quem gerencia isso é o proprio sistema operacional, conforme necessário, fora que em um servidor não terá só um programa rodando, um sistema operacional é um composto de diversos programas, muitos já rodando, o processador não vai só servir a você, vai servir a tudo que estiver rodando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Node.js tem o módulo **cluster**, que permite que você inicie processos Worker que dividem as requisições na mesma porta.
Na prática, você inicia um número de processos igual ao número de cores do seu processador e aproveita ao máximo cada um.
Fonte: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/cluster.html

Comment: pô cara, era tipo isso mesmo ! Vlw